# Querying relational data in plugin

Tags: relations

I'm creating a plugin and I need help to query relational data.

Here's the table schema I have:

```
collection
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| id | label       | dateCreated         | dateUpdated         | uid |
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
|  1 | Static page | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 0   |
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+

collection_section
+----+---------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
| id | collectionId  | sectionId | dateCreated         | dateUpdated         | uid |
+----+---------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+
|  1 |             1 |        16 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 0   |
|  2 |             1 |         9 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 0   |
|  3 |             1 |        14 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 0   |
|  4 |             1 |        10 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 2016-03-11 16:19:07 | 0   |
+----+---------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----+

craft_content
+------------+
| title      |
+------------+
| mytitle    |
+------------+
```

I've created 2 records:

```
// collectionRecord
public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'collectionSection' => array(
            static::HAS_MANY,
            'collectionSectionRecord',
            'sectionId'
        )
    );
}

// collectionSectionRecord
public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'collection' => array(
            static::BELONGS_TO,
            'collectionRecord',
            'required' => true,
            'onDelete' => static::CASCADE
        ),
        'section'  => array(
            static::BELONGS_TO,
            'SectionRecord',
            'required' => true,
            'onDelete' => static::CASCADE
        ),
    );
}
```

The section ids are only singles and I need to get a listing of all the sections with their content related to the collectionId.

I tried this:

```
$query = craft()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('s.*')
    ->from('sections s')
    ->join('collection_section cs', 'cs.sectionId = s.id')
    ->where(array('cs.collectionId' => 1))
    ->queryAll();
return SectionModel::populateModels($query);
```

I actually get the sections from the craft_sections table but I need the related content (title row) "mytitle" in the craft_content table.
Is there an easy way to do that in Craft?

Comment: So, do you want this done through ActiveRecord or through querybuilder? To do the latter the relationships for AR don't matter - you're building the SQL query manually through querybuilder.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
$records = Plugin_CollectionSectionRecord::model()
        ->findAllByAttributes(['collectionId' => $collectionId]);
}

$ids = [];
foreach($records as $value) {
    $ids[] = $value->sectionId;
}

$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->elementType = 'Entry';
$criteria->sectionId = $ids;
$result = $criteria->all();
return $result;
```